# Error with ndk-gdb of android-ndk-r9d-linux-x86 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, android-ndk, ndk-gdb

I use ndk-gdb of android-ndk-r9d-linux-x86 in ubuntu 12.04 to debug the android native application "hello-jni", but it receive this error.

```
  WARNING: The shell running this script isn't bash.  Although we try to avoid bashism in               scripts, things can happen.
  .../adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140321/android-ndk-r9d/ndk-gdb: 143: .../adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140321/android-ndk-r9d/ndk-gdb: Bad substitution
  .../adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140321/android-ndk-r9d/ndk-gdb: 555: [: 1: unexpected operator
  .../adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140321/android-ndk-r9d/ndk-gdb: 771: [: armeabi-v7a: unexpected operator
```

but the android-ndk-r8e-linux-x86 is ok, i wonder why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe 'ndk-gdb' has been deprecated in favor of 'ndk-gdb.py'  (although this has not been widely advertised, IMO.)  Using r9d, I had the same problem you reported above, but the python version worked without issue.

Answer (score 0):

`WARNING: The shell running this script isn't bash.  Although we try to avoid bashism in scripts, things can happen.` --- This means you are using something like dash.

Change /bin/sh to /bin/bash will solve the warning and the "bad substitution" problem.